# Supabase-js: querying foreign table returns null

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I have a table Requests with 2 foreign keys referencing auth.users and Categories

```
Requests
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| user_id (= auth.users.id) | title | description | category_id (= categories.id)
|
|

Categories
-------------------------------
| id | category | description
```

I can't seem to return category from Categories the way it's described in the docs :

```
let { data: requests, error } = await supabase
  .from('requests')
  .select(`
    some_column,
    other_table (
      foreign_key
    )
  `)
```

tried these and other similar variations

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('requests').select(`
  title,
  description,
  categories:category_id ( category )

`)

const { data, error } = await supabase.from('requests').select(`
  title,
  description,
  categories ( category )

`)
```

but all i get is this, and i have no clue how to get the column i want from the other table!

```
data: [
    {
      title: 'title',
      description: 'description',
      categories: null
    }
  ],
```

Update: solved by replacing the backticks (from the documentation https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/select) with regular ticks ' '

Comment: Let's keep it simple, and see what you get with this `const { data, error } = await supabase.from('requests').select('*, categories(*)')`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked as your suggestion, with regular ticks ' instead of backticks ` as shown in the supabase docs.

This finally gave me the columns I needed: 

`const request = await supabase.from('requests').select(' title, description , categories(category)');`